# js socket io всегда connected false

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

появилась проблема. Я написал небольшой скрипт на node js с использованием socket io и express (цель скрипта - обрабатывать клиентские запросы с сайта на php). И все работало, пока я не переместил проект на хостинг. Путем долгих попыток я обнаружил, что если я использую (на frontend части) `let socket = io();` все работает, а если я передаю аргумент в io `let socket = io(location.host+':9998')`, то происходит подключение, но моментально отключается (socket.connected => false). Таким образом мне не удается использовать emit и другие функции для связи с сервером. Подскажите, что делать в такой ситуации?
P.s. просто io() я оставить не могу, т.к. сам сайт работает не php и на другом порту.

Comment: Мне кажется, что подробностей маловато. Не могли бы Вы больше написать про архитектуру проекта - "кто на ком стоял"? что работает на клиенте, что на сервере и причем здесь php?

Comment: Сам проект работает на php, но появилась потребность добавить socket.io для постоянного взаимодействия сервера с клиентом. А архитектура скрипта не имеет значение, т.к. что бы я не пробовал, всегда одна и та же проблема - user connected и все, соединение отрубается и, соответственно, перестает работать emit, а reconnect не помогает

Comment: То есть, всё, что делается с socket.io - происходит на клиенте? А что на стороне сервера принимает соединение?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение. На самом деле проблема была в версиях socketio. По стандарту вы получаете файл socketio для frontend после установки socketio через npm для node js.